# Inserting Data to a Database into the correct row using the session User Id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

Does anyone know how I would Insert data into a mysql database and in the correct row using the user Id in the session It will insert into the database but not in the correct row Here is the code I have tried.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
':user_id' => $_SESSION['user']['id'], 
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login (code, link)
VALUES ('You Found a Secret Game!', '/12283719823838hdhj/') WHERE id = :user_id ");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I tried using `':user_id' => $_SESSION['user']['id'],`but It didn't work.

Comment: I think you're 'preparing' the worng bit

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO login (code, link)
VALUES ('You Found a Secret Game!', '/12283719823838hdhj/') WHERE id = " . 
$_SESSION['user']['id']);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If you look at the SQL you are pushing through I think you will find it is trying to check where id = :user_id rather than the value of :user_id

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it still isn't working this time it isn't inserting into the database.